# Google tag manager Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

i have an issue with my gtm code sudently stopped recording data and i started getting this error.

"Invalid or unexpected token"

according to the dev tools  the error comes from

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src=“https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-149259800-1”></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag(‘js’, new Date());<------------------------HERE
  gtag(‘config’, ‘UA-SOMETHING’);
</script>
```

But even when i removed that line the error passed to  the next gtag() line
what could be causing this?.

Answer (score 6):

Use these single quote '' or double quote "" for parameters not ´´.

This being said change

```
gtag(‘js’, new Date());
gtag(‘config’, ‘UA-SOMETHING’);
```

for

```
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-SOMETHING');
```

this solved the issue for me.